# SSH to singleconnect (SSO) server using paramiko

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, single-sign-on, paramiko

I wrote a script that use ssh to connect (single-sign-on server) a single connect server from there i would like to  connect a node. But my problem is when i send a command through ssh invoke_shell, i can see it on the output but the command didn't executed. Any help related to single connect and paramiko would be well appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import paramiko
import time

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("host",port=2222,username="username",password="pass")
remote_con = ssh.invoke_shell()
print "Interactive SSH session established"
output = remote_con.recv(5000)
remote_con.send("device_ip_here_to_connect_from_SSO \n")
print output
time.sleep(3)
output = remote_con.recv(5000)
print output
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this script or the relevant parts of it.

Comment: Edited the question and script added.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `send('command\n')` instead of `send('command')` when sending the command.

Comment: I'm sure that im using it send("command \n") this way. The weird thing is when i read the output it looks where it should be but no response from server afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

The problem was sending the command like this

```
remote_con.send("device_ip_here_to_connect_from_SSO \n")
```

it should be like this

```
remote_con.send("device_ip_here_to_connect_from_SSO \r")
```